# Appdelegate.m Expected identifier or '(' problem, how can is solve it?

Tags: ios, xcode

What I am doing wrong?

I want to add to a script a Firebase Push Notification as the documentation shows:

```
    #import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Firebase.h>
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#if DEBUG
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
#import <RNCPushNotificationIOS.h>

static void InitializeFlipper(UIApplication *application) {
  FlipperClient *client = [FlipperClient sharedClient];
  SKDescriptorMapper *layoutDescriptorMapper = [[SKDescriptorMapper alloc] initWithDefaults];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitLayoutPlugin alloc] initWithRootNode:application withDescriptorMapper:layoutDescriptorMapper]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FKUserDefaultsPlugin alloc] initWithSuiteName:nil]];
  [client addPlugin:[FlipperKitReactPlugin new]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc] initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
  [client start];
}
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate

// Required to register for notifications
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}
// Required for the register event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
// Required for the notification event. You must call the completion handler after handling the remote notification.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
// Required for the registrationError event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}
// IOS 10+ Required for localNotification event
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler
{
  
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveNotificationResponse:response];
  
  completionHandler();
}
// IOS 4-10 Required for the localNotification event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  if ([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil) {
    [FIRApp configure];
  }
}
    

{
#if DEBUG
  InitializeFlipper(application);
#endif

  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"shopinnadmin"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  
  UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
  center.delegate = self;
  
  [FIRApp configure];
  return YES;
  
  
}
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{
  completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}
 

@end
```

Expected identifier or '(' in the line 75.

I don't want to write the whole code again, so can you help me, how to format correctly?
The push notifications won't appear and i try to figure it out why.

I added this lines, hope that this lines missed, but i can't figure it out, why it gives me an error:

```
{
  if ([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil) {
    [FIRApp configure];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove two lines:

Line 72: }
Line 75: {